# How to skip a line when reading file (was:How to index through a file?)

Tags: python, string, list, file

I have data that has to be read and plotted using the graphics library. I'm able to split the data into a list except I want to skip the first list.

```
     from graphics import *
    def main():
       data = input("Type in the filename: ")
infile = open(data, "r")


for aline in infile:
    # I try using read() but I get one output 
    data1 = infile.readline() 
    dataLst = aline.split('","')
    print(dataLst[1])
 main()
```

#### output:

```
     close <--- How to skip this line?
     720.11
     720.1100
     721.0700
```

Here is a sample of the data, the bold are data I want to print out: 
"date","close","volume","open","high","low"

"16:00",**"720.11"**,"1,919,799","720.71","723","716.68"
"2012/12/19",**"720.1100"**,"1918493.0000","720.7100","723.0000","716.6800"
"2012/12/18",**"721.0700"**,"3004838.0000","716.6000","729.1000","715.0500"

Comment: A side note: since you are dealing with comma-separted-values (CSV) file, look into the [csv](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html) module.

Comment: cannot use the cvs module or the next() function. What would be the beginner's way of reading this kind of data?

Comment: Why not `next()`? Is this a homework?

Comment: `cannot use the cvs module or the next() function.` That is silly. Why use Python then? Use C or Assembly. Sounds like homework.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `next()` function to skip the first line:

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    next(f) # Skip one line
    for line in f:
        print line
```

## Update

I don't know why the original poster dislike `next()`, but if the PO insist, use `readline()` instead:

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    f.readline() # Skip one line
    for line in f:
        print line
```

Answer (score 1):

Your life will be easier if you use the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
import csv

with open(fn, 'r') as f:
    data=csv.reader(f)
    header=next(data)
    for line in data:
        print line[1]
```

Prints:

```
720.11
720.1100
721.0700
```

Answer (score 1):

If you call `readline()` before the `for` loop but don't keep its output then that line is just dropped:

```
infile.readline()
for aline in infile:
    # I try using read() but I get one output 
    data1 = infile.readline() 
    dataLst = aline.split('","')
    print(dataLst[1])
```

This is basically the same as calling the `next` function on `infile`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that behaves properly in both Python 2 and 3:

```
import csv
import sys

if sys.hexversion < 0x3000000:
    # Python 2.x
    csv_open_read = lambda fname: open(fname, "rb")
    inp = raw_input
else:
    # Python 3.x
    csv_open_read = lambda fname: open(fname, "r", newline="")
    inp = input

def read_csv(fname, skip_header=False, **kwargs):
    with csv_open_read(fname) as inf:
        if skip_header:
            next(inf, None)
        for row in csv.reader(inf, **kwargs):
            yield row

def main():
    fname = inp("Type in the filename: ").strip()
    closes = [float(row[1]) for row in read_csv(fname, skip_header=True)]

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score -3):

You shouldn't write this program because it already exists and it's called tail.

```
$ cat skip
close
720.11
720.1100
721.0700
$ tail -n +2 skip
720.11
720.1100
721.0700
```

http://www.unix.com/man-page/POSIX/1posix/tail/